# how can i use server timezone in new Date() of the user javascript digital clock?

Tags: javascript

i have this javascript code:

```
<div id="page-top">
<div id="topbar">

<table>
<td bgcolor="#8BC5FF" height="40" width="40">
<img src="../images/clock/dg8.gif" name="hr1"><img 
src="../images/clock/dg8.gif" name="hr2"><img 
src="../images/clock/dgc.gif" name="c"><img 
src="../images/clock/dg8.gif" name="mn1"><img 
src="../images/clock/dg8.gif" name="mn2"><img 
src="../images/clock/dgc.gif" name="c"><img 
src="../images/clock/dg8.gif" name="se1"><img 
src="../images/clock/dg8.gif" name="se2"><img 
src="../images/clock/dgpm.gif" name="ampm">
</td></table>

<script language="javascript">
dg0 = new Image();dg0.src = "../images/clock/dg0.gif";
dg1 = new Image();dg1.src = "../images/clock/dg1.gif";
dg2 = new Image();dg2.src = "../images/clock/dg2.gif";
dg3 = new Image();dg3.src = "../images/clock/dg3.gif";
dg4 = new Image();dg4.src = "../images/clock/dg4.gif";
dg5 = new Image();dg5.src = "../images/clock/dg5.gif";
dg6 = new Image();dg6.src = "../images/clock/dg6.gif";
dg7 = new Image();dg7.src = "../images/clock/dg7.gif";
dg8 = new Image();dg8.src = "../images/clock/dg8.gif";
dg9 = new Image();dg9.src = "../images/clock/dg9.gif";
dgam= new Image();dgam.src= "../images/clock/dgam.gif";
dgpm= new Image();dgpm.src= "../images/clock/dgpm.gif";
dgc = new Image();dgc.src = "../images/clock/dgc.gif";

function dotime(){ 
theTime=setTimeout('dotime()',1000);
d = new Date();
hr= d.getHours()+100;
mn= d.getMinutes()+100;
se= d.getSeconds()+100;
if(hr==100){hr=112;am_pm='am';}
else if(hr<112){am_pm='am';}
else if(hr==112){am_pm='pm';}
else if(hr>112){am_pm='pm';hr=(hr-12);}
tot=''+hr+mn+se;
document.hr1.src = '../images/clock/dg'+tot.substring(1,2)+'.gif';
document.hr2.src = '../images/clock/dg'+tot.substring(2,3)+'.gif';
document.mn1.src = '../images/clock/dg'+tot.substring(4,5)+'.gif';
document.mn2.src = '../images/clock/dg'+tot.substring(5,6)+'.gif';
document.se1.src = '../images/clock/dg'+tot.substring(7,8)+'.gif';
document.se2.src = '../images/clock/dg'+tot.substring(8,9)+'.gif';
document.ampm.src= '../images/clock/dg'+am_pm+'.gif';}
dotime();
</script>
</div>
</div>
```

this code allow the user to see a Digital clock, its work good, put the problem that i want to use this clock with my current timezone (EET) not the user timezone. (the timezone of the server, not to the client). how can i do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
d = new Date();
```

you need to inject the server time:

```
d = new Date(<%=year%>, <%=month%>, <%=day%>, <%=hours%>, <%=minutes%>, <%=seconds%>, <%=milliseconds%>);
```

where obviously those are server side variables representing the server time and you should adapt the syntax based on the server side language you are using.

Here are the [different overloads](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/global_objects/date) of the `Date` constructor you could use to assign it to some given date.

Comment: d = new Date(<%=year%>, <%=month%>, <%=day%>, <%=hours%>, <%=minutes%>, <%=seconds%>, <%=milliseconds%>); didn't work, i will try "different overloads"

Comment: @mbayloon, what server side language you are using?

Comment: no, i don't have a server side program and client side, i deploy my grails application to a server the timezone of the server is EET

Comment: thx Darin Dimitrov, thx all i find the answer to be with GMT timezone.